# Program that finds the length of the longest STRING that has no repeated characters

Tags: c, string

I need help fixing a program that finds the length of the longest STRING that has no repeated characters. For example, the character string “dvdf” should return 3 because the longest string without repeating characters is “vdf”. The program should return but it returns 4.

details
details
details
details
details
details
details
details
details
details
details
details
details
details
details

```
#include <stdio.h>
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char *);

int main(void) {
  char *str = "dvdf";
  int result = lengthOfLongestSubstring(str);
  printf("%d", result);

  return 0;
}

int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char *s){
    int startpos = 0, curposition = 0, maxlen = 0;
    int positions[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        positions[i] = -1;
    }

    while (s[curposition] != '\0') {
        char curchar = s[curposition];
        if (positions[curchar] != -1 && positions[curchar] > startpos) {
          int len = curposition - startpos;
          if (len > maxlen) maxlen = len;
          startpos = positions[curchar] + 1;
        }

        positions[curchar] = curposition;
        curposition++;
    }
    int len = curposition - startpos;
    if (len > maxlen) maxlen = len;
    return maxlen;
}
```

I tried reworking he whole program but it didn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: sounds like a school homework

Comment: pls mark a correct answer at least

Answer (score 1):

Because you have the if condition wrong. It should be greater or equal startpos.

```
if (positions[curchar] != -1 && positions[curchar] >= startpos)
```

Why? Because first, you save `positions["d"] = 0`, and when you hit the second "d", the condition is evaluated as `(positions["d"] = 0 > startpos = 0) = false`.

Also you can optimise the condition to just

```
if (positions[curchar] >= startpos)
```

because `startpos` will never be `-1`, hence it covers the `positions[curchar] != -1`